# DNN Skin Issue (VB to C# conversion)

Tags: dotnetnuke

I need assistance with a DNN skin issue. Here's the background.

I have functionality in one of my legacy VB DNN skins that writes the full URL of the parent page. The code is:

```
<% If PortalSettings.ActiveTab.Level > (0) Then Response.Write(PortalSettings.ActiveTab.BreadCrumbs(PortalSettings.ActiveTab.Level-1).FullUrl) %>
```

This works fine in my legacy VB skins. However, I am now using a different skin set written in C#. When I apply the above code to the C# skin, it returns the following error message:

> Could Not Load Theme: /Portals/_default/Skins/cust08/InteriorSub.ascx,
>   Error:
>   c:\inetpub\vhosts\dnnpro.com\httpdocs\Portals_default\Skins\cust08\InteriorSub.ascx(107):
>   error CS1002: ; expected

I tried tweaking the code, but no success. I'm sure this is an easy fix, but I'm stumped!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The error there is pretty specific You need to put a Semi colon after the code, it is C#

The code you'll likely use would be

```
<%

If (PortalSettings.ActiveTab.Level >0) 
{
Response.Write(PortalSettings.ActiveTab.BreadCrumbs(PortalSettings.ActiveTab.Level-1).FullUrl);
}
%>
```